# Limit of a function without LH

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate the limit : ${((1+x)^{1/x} -e})/x$  when x tends to zero.

This  can be solved using L-Hopital rule , however  I was wondering if there is any other method to do it, like any series formula or any other thing?

Comment: What does LH mean?

Comment: @fwd lhopital  rule in limits

Comment: This is a derivative, so it will be hard to have a well-defined dividing line between L'Hopital and any other method.

Comment: For small $x,y>0$, one has $(1+x)^{1/x}=e^{1-x/2+x^2/3...}$ and $e^{1+y}-e=ey+O(y^2)$ so using this with $y=-x/2+x^2/3-..$ works but not sure that is any diferent than L-Hopital

Answer (score 0):

Considering
$$y=\frac{(1+x)^{\frac 1x} -e}x$$ compose Taylor series
$$a=(1+x)^{\frac 1x}\implies \log(a)=\frac 1x\log(1+x)$$
$$\log(a)=\frac 1x\left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+O\left(x^4\right) \right)=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}+O\left(x^3\right)$$
$$a=e^{\log(a)}=e-\frac{e x}{2}+\frac{11 e x^2}{24}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ Just finish : you will get not only the limit but also how it is approached.